# Placement problem in regex over 700 matches in a long doc

Tags: regex, vba, replace, ms-word

I have to modify more than 700 biblio references to put them into footnotes in a document of hundred pages. So, I'm looking at VBA Word, but I 'm almost totally newbie. Documentation seems hard to find, especially as regards to basis (object model, etc.).
Here it is what I've tried and the major problem I'm facing with described after. The sketch of the code used is as follows:

```
Sub Replace_ref_1()
' Definition of all variables'

Set docRange = ActiveDocument.Range

' Definition of the Regex needed  '
With regEx
   ... 
End With

Options.Overtype = False ' Insert and not delete '
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False ' Out of tracking changes mode '
' Regex matchs '
Set regFound = regEx.Execute(docRange)

' Loop over results, going by the last (highest index) '
For cpt = regFound.Count To 1 Step -1
    refText = regFound(cpt - 1)
    Selection.SetRange Start:=regFound.Item(cpt - 1).FirstIndex, End:=regFound.Item(cpt - 1).FirstIndex
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    Selection.Footnotes.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:=LTrim(refText)
Next cpt

End Sub
```

The idea is to use the index of each match (which is, if I understand it well, the number of the begining character of the matched string) to insert a footnote at this place.
I meet the following problem: numbers (mark) of footnotes are not inserted at the correct place. In general, a few to some dozens of characters before expected. I thought it was due to the fact that adding footnotes implied adding characters to the text, and so the index couldn't be OK. That's why I tried processing from the last to the first: cf. "downto" loop. (I checked before this try that matches were in increasing index by writing them in a file.) But this is not better...

I noticed also that for a portion of text with only 3 matches, it's OK. But as soon as the text is too long, it doesn't work, either with the first or the last matches. I also noticed that it is better if I remove the summary (which lies at the begining), but even with that "trick", for a portion of doc with 133 matches, only the 57 first are OK, and all that follow are shifted (without any change in format between the 57th and 58th match...).

I guess there may be a problem in my understanding of index, or, moreover, in the portion of text included in the indexes...

I would be glad if someone could help me about that.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: links to 3 docs

1) input.doc (the entry) --> http://dl.free.fr/jlfRDviRe

2) output.doc (what it should look like at the end) --> http://dl.free.fr/hNu2IAUMp

3) obtained.doc (what is get with the code above) --> http://dl.free.fr/b5OF5PKCL

N.B. Docs realized from a doc found on internet and modified...

**EDIT 2** (19-03-07): New doc which is the whole doc I used with the same format (the text having been anonymized), the same style, etc. Note that the 5th first chapters (until page 31) show the output wanted. So the macro will find only matches starting page 32...

4) --> http://dl.free.fr/fGzSid05k

Comment: Would be easier to understand if you post a sample doc or a part of it (input) and a post of how you want it (output).

Comment: OK, how can I add docs?

Comment: You can upload it to onedrive, google drive or any other major service provider and paste the link in your question

Comment: Done! 3 docs with input, output and obtained.

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/41837-regex-over-700-matches-long-doc.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: I am sorry for the "cross-posted". I didn't know the habits, but I've just read the etiquette and from now on, I will mention it explicitely if I feel I have to use it. 
(And indeed, I asked the question in a French forum but didn't get answer, so I thought it would be hard to get one if I didn't multiply the sites...)

(NB : This message is copy from the other site.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

See the comments in the code so you have an idea of what's going on

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessFootnotes()

    Dim wordRange As Word.Range

    Dim startText As String
    Dim endText As String
    Dim footnoteText As String
    Dim footnoteCounter As Long

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' To begin searching the whole document again
    Set wordRange = ActiveDocument.Content

    ' You have to escape the characters with "\" otherwise they are invalid
    startText = "\(\["
    endText = "\]\)"

    ' Initialize the footnote counter
    footnoteCounter = 1

    ' Clear formatting to be sure there's nothing saved in the settings before
    wordRange.Find.ClearFormatting
    wordRange.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With wordRange.Find
        ' This will look for text contained between start and end text
        .Text = startText & "*" & endText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        wordRange.Find.Execute

        ' Loop to find in the whole document
        While wordRange.Find.Found

            ' Maintain word alive
            DoEvents

            ' Remove both parenthesis
            footnoteText = Replace(Replace(wordRange.Text, "(", ""), ")", "")

            ' Insert the footnote
            ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add wordRange, , footnoteText

            ' Remove the original text
            wordRange.Text = ""

            ' Increase the footnote counter
            footnoteCounter = footnoteCounter + 1

            ' Search the next one
            wordRange.Find.Execute
        Wend

    End With

Sub_Exit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    GoTo Sub_Exit


End Sub
```

Let me know if it works (I tested it with your input file) and if it does, please remember to mark the answer.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but it doesn't work on my file. Footnotes numbers are duplicate (in my doc still exist footnotes), and large portions of text are included in the footnotes, not only the reference... :-( Thanks for the try.

Comment: I didn’t see any existing footnotes in the sample document

Comment: I have updated the code to use word auto-numbering of footnotes. See line:                 ' Insert the footnote
                ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add wordRange, , footnoteText

Comment: Replace the whole code in your document and try again.

Comment: Indeed, there are not footnotes in the sample document, but it is just a sample... In my "real" doc, there is a 3 pages introduction-like (with some footnotes), then a summary  (on 2 pages), then about 55 chapters with a title (styled) and texts with some footnotes from time to time, and an ended chapter "bibliography" with a table containing the extended references...

I've just tried the new code, but the result is the same.

Comment: Post a sample doc that contains other footnotes so I can test it. Also, what word version do you have?

Comment: Done! Word version used is 2010 in general (it can change, sometimes 2013).

Comment: Sorry. Couldn't understand where the text to be transformed in footnotes is in the new document you posted.

Comment: See for example (foot)note 3 (page 4), 6 (6), 8 (9), 9 (10), 10 (12), etc.

Comment: Yes I see those. But the ones you have to turn into footnotes I don’t

Comment: First one is "([NMU], p. 20)" (p. 31), then "([CMO], p. 28)" (p. 31), "([DDM], p. 10)" (p. 36), "([DLV], p. 21)" (p. 37), "([REY], p. 129)" (p. 37) and many many more after...

Comment: An answer using Search method has been given in the MS Forum, and I gave a method using the Regex too. Some questions remain about Regex. If anyone has clues about them...